# Filtering and summarizing a CSV file by occurence of name

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file of virus names and data information:

[image: This is the image of the csv file.]

I need to write a script that gathers information based on the occurrence of virus names.

The image shows the file already filtered by the word "grapevine" for convenience.

For each virus with the keyword "grapevine" in it:

I need to gather specific information. 
 1. the number of times it is found in the file
 2. the range of length for that specific grapevine virus
 3. the summation of reads for that that specific grapevine virus

How do I parse the virus name "grapevine" without specifying each type?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in counting the occurences of the virus names, such as "grapevine", loop over all lines of the csv file and count lines that contain the virus name. Without more information on the csv file layout, this is the best we could - most likely - do:

```
csv = ... # Store the csv reader instance
needle = "FOOO"
result = len([line for line in csv if needle in line])
```